# Is it possible to link the bottom inset of a component to another one with the (new) GUI Builder of Codename One?

Tags: codenameone

I am using the (new) GUI Builder to design a form. I want a component to be X mm away from the top of the screen and Y mm above another component
I achieved to set the top inset but could not realize my goal for the bottom inset because when I select the link icon and drag it to the southern component this latter is not highlighted as shown below.

[image: cannot link bottom inset to southern component]

I know I could define the top inset of the bottom component instead but then I'll have to compute the bottom inset of the top component to the window bottom border so that everything fits together although I don't know the bottom component total height.

So I wonder if linking the bottom inset to the just below component is even possible in the GUI Builder ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So when you drag the bottom "link" handle of the top component over the bottom component, it doesn't get highlighted?  Likely this is because the bottom component depends on the top component in some way.  It doesn't let you add circular dependencies.

From the screenshot you posted, I see that you have 3 incoming links into the top component: "StartFlag", "FinishFlag", and "ProgressSlider".

You may need to remove some of these links so that you can link the top component to the bottom component.

Comment: Thanks Steve I'll look for circular dependencies. So if the bottom component has a link on the left and right sides of the top component, then the top component cannot have a bottom link to the bottom component, right ? And if the top and bottom component are linked for the side imsets to a common third one (eg the guide label the one that you use on top in the tutorial to always have the same side insets). Will it be possible to do my goal ?

Comment: That's right.  If component B's layout depends on component A's layout in any way, (top, left, bottom, or right), then component A cannot depend on component B.  It is conceivable that in the future this restriction could be lifted so that horizontal constraints and vertical constraints are mutually exclusive, but for now that's how it works.  You can work around this by making an invisible "guide" component to which you align the right and left sides of both the top and bottom comps - so they don't depend on each other.

Comment: Thanks Steve for the clear explanation! I know what I have to do regarding this:-)!